# Can I have tabs on the left stacked vertically?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I found an extension `tree style tab` - it can move tabs to the left, but it stacks them horizontally - while I want the stacked vertically.

I would like the following layout in Firefox:

[image: Screenshot]

The screenshot is from Notepad++ with the "Vertical" "Tab Bar" setting enabled.

**Edit**:

Several verical rows are allowed but not required.

Comment: So you want something like [this](https://static-ssl-cdn.addons.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/30/30846.png?modified=1331247702)? Just to clarify: vertically means up and down (panel on the left), horizontally means left and right (bar on the top).

Comment: Nope - I want the text in the tab be vertical.

Comment: `Notepad++` has such option... But I don't have it near my self to make a screenshot.

Comment: So you want [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw2J7.png)?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! But in firefox. Can You help?

Comment: [This](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Move_the_tab_bar_%28Firefox%29) is the most promising lead, but apparently only works in FF 1. If you could find an updated version, or manage to edit an existing plugin like [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/vertical-tabs/), you could probably just swap a `vertical` and `horizontal` somewhere. I can't find any ready-made addons, but you can probably edit one like [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/vertical-tabs/) if you feel like learning a bit about Firefox addons.

Comment: Vertical text is rather complicated when using the Gecko platform which is why Firefox extensions using it are pretty rare.